# How can I rearrange image/text grid on media query?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have multiple rows of a grid where there is text in one column and an image in the other. For every row the order is reversed so that i looks nice on desktop-mode. The HTML is rendered from a CMS, so the **order is set by the user and is dynamic**.

[image]

For mobile mode I would however always want to have the image on top, and then the text below. How can I rearrange my grid to do this on a media query?

I have a fiddle here on how it works on desktop, but no Idea how to do the media query to always get the image on top, and text below. Im guessing flexbox might be able to solve this somehow? All help greatly appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/3opref6L/

This code gets rendered by the CMS and might be longer or shorter.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="block htmlblock">
                <p style="text-align: left;">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="block image-block">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="block image-block">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="block htmlblock">
                <p style="text-align: left;">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="block htmlblock">
                <p style="text-align: left;">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="block image-block">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **DYNAMIC SOLUTION with *flexbox* on top of the *Bootstrap***  and `This will work on any number of rows` dynamically. *Since Bootstrap is based on Flexbox itself*, This solution worked for us.

**UPDATE:**  Some fixes performed to override bootstrap specific CSS:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container .row:nth-child(2n-1) .col:first-child {
    order: 2;
  }

  .container .row:nth-child(2n-1) .col:last-child {
    order: 1;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .container .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row !important;
  }

  .container .row .col:first-child {
    order: 1;
  }

  .container .row .col:last-child {
    order: 2;
  }
}

/* Bug Fix */
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .col-sm-12 {
    flex: 0 0 50% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./OrderIssue.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="block htmlblock">
            <p style="text-align: left">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="block image-block">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="block image-block">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="block htmlblock">
            <p style="text-align: left">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="block htmlblock">
            <p style="text-align: left">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="block image-block">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Using a class is usually easier:

`flex-sm-column-reverse flex-md-row`

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/NWRgejr

Answer (score 0):

if you use bootstrap 4 in this version of bootstrap used flex box to grid systems .
There are good features in Flexbox, one of which is the possibility of flex-direction . in this feature you can set row-reverse and resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I need to introduce a new class for make the same structure you want use class `flex-row-reverse` class with `row`. it works perfect as you want.

This is the small code to understand what I want to tell.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-5">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <p>TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-5 flex-row-reverse">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <p>TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-5">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <p>TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-5 flex-row-reverse">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <p>TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```